# How to embed ESRI maps on my website

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, html, embeddable-web-maps

I've got a website where I'd like to insert maps with some placemarks (restaurants, points of interest, ...). I'm tired of Google Maps and like to use ESRI basemaps. Is it possible to do this?

I'd like to create these maps directly from my webpages (with JavaScript) and without embeding ArcGIS online maps (I suppose this would require to create the map in 'arcgis.com' before).

Is it possible with any ESRI JavaScript API?

Answer (score 3):

**Possible with the ESRI JavaScript API**

Note you will need to know the map id in this  example it is '5b9675ca7ca9426a99ced88f66b42331'

> var mapDeferred =
>   esri.arcgis.utils.createMap("5b9675ca7ca9426a99ced88f66b42331", "map"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Topographic Map

```
<style>
  html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  .esriScalebar{
    padding: 20px 20px;
  }
  #map{
    padding:0;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");

  var map;

  function init() {
    var mapDeferred = esri.arcgis.utils.createMap("5b9675ca7ca9426a99ced88f66b42331", "map", {
        mapOptions: {
          slider: true,
          nav:false,
          wrapAround180:true
        }
      });
      mapDeferred.then(function(response){
        map = response.map;

        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', map,map.resize);
      });
  }

  dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/map_main/index.html